# How to create an evenly spaced timeseries for forecasting

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a forecast but this is the error that I get:

[image]

I am working with about 300,000 rows of data. Most of the report has already been built. My data just doesn't cotain certain dates. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So you're not satisfied with just an answer, but it has to be "as quickly and efficiently as possible" too? However, you didn't put much effort into your question.

Comment: Yes I shouldn't have included it. I've removed it now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue boils down to the problem of "How to create an evenly spaced timeline". You can easily achieve this in PowerQuery

1. Create a separate daily date table.
2. Outer join your observations onto the dates, which will give you "null" for the unobserved days
3. Apply the "fill down" operation on your values column, which basically means that the last value will be repeated until a new observation appears.

These evenly distributed time series is suitable for ML forecasting, at least when it comes to predicting trends. But the real power of this feature in Power BI is in predicting seasonality, and you most likely won't get that right with the above interpolation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution to this problem.